# Iterate through 14 day increments to find average of all max values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Daily Risk Score
Date    
2020-07-07  13.0
2020-07-08  8.0
2020-07-09  8.0
2020-07-10  8.0
2020-07-11  8.0
... ...
2020-07-16  13.0
2020-07-17  11.0
2020-07-18  9.0
2020-07-19  9.0
2020-07-20  9.0
```

The total dataframe is 9478 rows long. The data starts on 7-07 and goes through 07-20. However, it repeats 677 times (each time represents a different location). In essence, each location is assigned a score on each of the 14 days, and then they are all listed. So for example the first 14 days will be New York city, the second 14 days will be Los Angeles, the next 14 days will be a different city and so on.

What I am looking to do is find the max of each location through the 14 day period and average all of those maxes together.

```
Daily Risk Score
Date    
2020-07-07  13.0
2020-07-08  8.0
2020-07-09  8.0
2020-07-10  8.0
2020-07-11  8.0
2020-07-12  8.0
2020-07-13  10.0
2020-07-14  7.0
2020-07-15  7.0
2020-07-16  10.0
2020-07-17  13.0
2020-07-18  13.0
2020-07-19  13.0
2020-07-20  13.0
2020-07-07  8.0
2020-07-08  8.0
2020-07-09  8.0
2020-07-10  8.0
2020-07-11  8.0
2020-07-12  8.0
2020-07-13  8.0
2020-07-14  8.0
2020-07-15  8.0
2020-07-16  9.0
2020-07-17  10.0
2020-07-18  10.0
2020-07-19  8.0
2020-07-20  8.0
2020-07-07  9.0
2020-07-08  24.0
2020-07-09  25.0
2020-07-10  13.0
2020-07-11  24.0
2020-07-12  23.0
2020-07-13  25.0
2020-07-14  25.0
2020-07-15  25.0
2020-07-16  25.0
2020-07-17  25.0
2020-07-18  24.0
2020-07-19  21.0
2020-07-20  20.0
```

In the example above then, the first location's max would be 13, the second would be 10, and the last location would be 25. I then want to average these together, which in this case would equal 16. How would I then apply this to all 677 locations?

Comment: Something like `df.groupby('location').rolling(14).max().groupby('location').mean()`?

Comment: The location isn't a column name though. I just know that the location changes every 14 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `groupby` every 14 rows using `np.arange` with the length of your dataframe df divided by 14 to "simulate a group for each location", get the `max` and then `mean`:

```
print (df['score'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//14).max().mean())
16.0
```